# JS Regex to check that string only includes anchor

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will return true only when the string only contains an anchor like so `<a href="www.something.com">Link</a>`.

Currently I have the following regex which almost works `(?=.*^<a)(?=.*<\/a>).*/g`

This works for the following scenarios:

`<a href="www.something.com">Link</a>` - Matches successfully

`words before <a href="www.something.com">Link</a>` - No matches - success

`<a href="www.something.com">Link</a> words after` - finds match - Not successful :(

I think I'm pretty close, I just need to know how to not find a match if there are any characters after the `</a>`.

Comment: Use `$` to match the end of the string after `</a>`

Comment: What if it contains two anchors, like `<a ...>foo</a>something else<a ...>bar</a>`

Comment: ^ = beginning of string "^<" = starts with "<", $ = end of string ">$" = ends with ">"

Comment: Also, consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3930247

Comment: There's no need to use the `g` modifier if you're using a regexp for testing, rather than returning the matching part of a string or replacing.

Comment: It's also not useful if you want to match the whole string.

Comment: `^<a[^>]+>[^>]+>$` this won't allow multiple links in one string, addressing Barmar's note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `$` after the last `>`

`(?=.*^<a)(?=.*<\/a>$).*`

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dtGNQO/1)

Alternatively, [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/BpO0wE/1) matches links and discards everything else, irregardless of whether there are one or more links in the same line.

`<a.*?\/a>`

Comment: Amazing, thanks for this! I was very close, just hadn't put the last character after the angle.